# Infinite control with ScrollBar nested inside a ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, xaml

Could someone explain to me why the following XAML does not work the way I expect it to and if there are any workarounds for it?

I Expect the TextBox to respect the Min- and MaxHeight properties of the RowDefinition it uses. Instead it's MaxHeight is used to mask the available space, but at the sametime it's content is growing behind the mask... Ehhhh?!

The behavior I expect is the same as when you give the RowDefinition a non-infinite Height, 2 scrollbars. One ScrollBar for the TextBox and one for the rest of the screen.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="200" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Content="Top" />

        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" AcceptsReturn="True" xml:space="preserve" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

            ***Enter a lot of text including enters here!***

        </TextBox>

        <Button Content="Bottom" Grid.Row="2" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Hope someone can help me with this problem.

Thanks,

Wim

Answer (score 0):

Setting min and max height on the TextBox allows the scrollbars to appear correctly.

```
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                     AcceptsReturn="True"
                     xml:space="preserve"
                     MinHeight="100"
                     MaxHeight="200"
                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                     HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

Comment: You are correct sir. The MinHeight will not be used though, and it doesn't explain why it's needed to set both the properties on the RowDefinition aswell as the child control. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed some strange behaviour.

Seems like a combination of the Grid itself having no size constraints (being inside a ScrollViewer and having no Height set) and the RowDefinition having no Height set to an absolute Value doesn't correctly constrain the TextBox.

If you absolutely need this constellation and don't want to depend on anything else you can do this:

```
<RowDefinition MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="200" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Comment: That seemed to work at first, BUT, the ActualHeight property of the RowDefinition is not a DependencyProperty. Thus you don't receive any updates to your GUI, kinda strange imo. And if you don't receive any updates, the prop will forever hold the value of the MinHeight. Would've been awesome if it was this simple though. :)

Comment: @Willy: Indeed - not a DependencyProperty, which makes this whole case even more strange. As others seem to have [similar problems](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/209925/494033.aspx), this looks like a bug to me.